# Combine reviews with object

Tags: json

My final stage is to combine the above with public reviews which are in a txt file. Basically, when the program has given the user the two most closest tv's, I am trying to output the review for the two closest matched tv's. Inside the txt file each case as a ID 1, 2, 3 etc and I have txt files for each case review named 1.txt, 2.txt etc so it matches the ID, if somebody can point me in the right direction pls??

Comment: what is the issue you are having?

Comment: I am struggling to figure out how to introduce a txt file that consists of a review of a tv. When the program prints out print(casebase[mostSimilar]) and print(casebase[mostSimilar2nd]) I also want there review which is in a serperate txt file? Hope it makes sense

Comment: you mean you have a number `mostSimilar` and you want to open a file named by that number with `.txt` extension? [that sounds farmiliar...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110140/attach-random-value#comment59862187_36110140) `print(open("{}.txt".format(mostSimilar)).read())`

Comment: It's something similar to that but  inside the casebase text file I have 8 tv's which have an ID for example                                                                    1, "Samsung UE32J5100 FULL HD 1080P", 32, 45, 1080, 189
---------------------------------2, "Song KDL-40R453C FULL HD 1080P", 40, 66, 1080, 269                                 as you can see 1 and 2 is the ID column. furthermore I then have reviews for both of these tv's call 1.txt for ID.1 and 2.txt for ID.2 and so when these tv's are print(casebase[mostSimilar] I want the review for that tv to be printed as wel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when your program gets to this line:

```
print(casebase[mostSimilar])
```

the value of `casebase[mostSimilar]` represents the line of the casebase file that is most similar, so the first element of it `casebase[mostSimilar][0]` will be the tv id for that tv. so the filename for the review of that tv will be:

```
"{}.txt".format(casebase[mostSimilar][0])
```

Then you can open that file and print the contents:

```
def main():

    ...

    print("Most Similar Watch: ")
    print(casebase[mostSimilar])

    with open("{}.txt".format(casebase[mostSimilar][0])) as review1:
        print(review1.read())

    print("Second Most Similar Watch: ")
    print(casebase[mostSimilar2nd])

    with open("{}.txt".format(casebase[mostSimilar2nd][0])) as review2:
        print(review2.read())

    ...
```

Comment: you really should clean up your code though... why don't you use the Television class for the TVs in the casebase file as well?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the ID, just compute the file name from the ID, then open the file and print its content.

Comment: would you be able to elaborate a bit more, please? Sorry it's new to me